# How can you have folds for a LaTeX file in XEmacs?

Tags: macos, emacs, folding, aquamacs

I would like to have automatic folds for comments in my AquaEmacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have similar folds as in Vim.
I could not put folds to specific lines.

However, there is an addon [Auctex](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/screenshots.html) which gives you Emacs-folds.
They are not as flexible as in Vim.

Please, inform me if you have found a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

have a look at [`hs-minor-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Hideshow.html). it's not automatic though. for a more automatic approach, i guess you could customize the hideshow mode the following way:

1. hide comments via `hs-hide-comments-when-hiding-all`
2. assign a function which hides nothing to `hs-hide-all-non-comment-function` and then
3. use `hs-hide-all` to hide all comments.

have not tried it. just an idea.

check out the [hideshow mode page at emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/HideShow) as well.

Comment: Did I understand right that it is not possible to get similar (automatic) folds to xEmacs as to Vim? I use xEmacs only for LaTex so I need folds only for it.